# Resize a <div> within a <td> and affect it to multiple cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

## Context

I've got a < table > with column headers that may represent different kinds or states of an object (for example, let's say that it could be animals or people). Row headers represent some characteristics of objects.

In another div in the page, I've got a list of instances (some  representing animals or people). I use drag and drop (using JQuery) to put them in cells of my table. After a < div> has been dropped in a < td>, until I left the page (submit the form), I'm still be able to drag it to another < td > (in case I made a mistake and place it to the wrong cell).

## The problem

Now, I would like to make my dropped object resizable to fill rows that is adjacent to it (for instance, to give him more than one characteristic). Also, after the resize action, the  object must retain draggable in another cell keeping it's new size (which represent characteristics).

I can't find a way to do deal with the resize action to do what I would like to do.

**How can I do that with html, javascript and/or Jquery?**

**Edit**:
An example of my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/B99KY/13/ (sorry if the js it's not very clean). I can drag element but I don't know how to handle resize action to do what I'm trying to achieve.

`var resizableHandler =  {
    handles: "s",
    start: function(e, ui) {
        console.log('resizing started');
    },
    resize: function(e, ui) {
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        console.log('resizing stopped');
    }
}`

For example, if I put "instance 1" in cell [charecteristic1, state1] and after that, I resize "instance 1" to fill charecteristic2 and charecteristic3, I would like to have "instance 1" which fill completely the news cell (to use them later after submit of this tab).

Comment: Why not make a class for when it's dropped?

Comment: Could you please add some html? The part with multiple cells is unclear... if I understand it correctly and you want to set same div on top of multiple cells... well... that will so suck to define.

Comment: a jsfiddle or codepen example will be very helpful to better understand the issue

Comment: I edited my post and shared a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your interest to my problem.

Comment: @Agony How can a class solve my resize problem? What kinds of properties could be useful in this class?